# How to replace specific section of text in a file, with text from url in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to replace some text in a file with text from a url link.  I have gotten close, but the result has unintended complications.

Here is the text of the file I need to do this with (wp-config.php):

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the installation.
 * You don't have to use the web site, you can copy this file to "wp-config.php"
 * and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * Database settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** Database settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'database_name_here' );

/** Database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'username_here' );

/** Database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here' );

/** Database hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );

/** Database charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );

/** The database collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );

/**#@+
 * Authentication unique keys and salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases! You can generate these using
 * the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}.
 *
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies.
 * This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define( 'AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here' );

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress database table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix = 'wp_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the documentation.
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/
 */
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );

/* Add any custom values between this line and the "stop editing" line. */



/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
```

I need to replace the section of salts with the ones in this link:

```
https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/
```

I believe there are escape characters in the salts complicating things for me as I am new to bash. Here is the closest I have gotten but this took some help:

```
cp wp-config.php wp-config.bak
curl https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ | awk -F "'" 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$4;next} {$4=a[$2]}1' OFS="'" - wp-config.php > wp-config.tmp
mv wp-config.tmp wp-config.php
cat wp-config.php
```

Once again, this creates new issues, while it does replace the salts section it also makes the file unreadable.  Hoping someone can help me tweak this, or show me a better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you trust the contents of the URL, you could replace (once) the `defines` lines in `wp-config.php` with:

```
require '/path/to/salts';
```

and then when you need new salts, just do something like:

```
url='https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/'

if salts=$(curl -fs "$url"); then
    printf '<?php\n%s\n' "$salts" > /path/to/salts
fi
```

You'll need to ensure that your webserver process has permission to read the salts file.

This is probably what is causing `wp-config.php` to become unreadable when you do your awk/mv:
if the user creating the temporary file creates it as `rw-------` for example (or as `rw-r----` but the webservice process does not run in the same group), then the webserver process will be unable to read the file.